# How to select all and Unselect checkbox in Angular?

Tags: angular, html

I am doing an angular Todo list. In that I am trying to do selectall and unselect all checkbox part.

todo.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from '../../services/todo.service';

import { Todo } from 'src/app/models/Todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: \['./todo-item.component.css'\]
})
export class TodoItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() todo: Todo;
  @Output() deleteTodo: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private todoService:TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // Set Dynamic Classes
  setClasses() {
    let classes = {
      todo: true,
      'is-complete': this.todo.completed
    }

    return classes;
  }

  onToggle(todo) {
    // Toggle in UI
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    // Toggle on server
    this.todoService.toggleCompleted(todo).subscribe(todo => console.log(todo));
  }

  onDelete(todo) {
    this.deleteTodo.emit(todo);
  }
checkUncheckAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
    this.checkUncheckAll\[i\].isSelected = this.todos;
  }
  this.checkUncheckAll();
}


}][1]][1]
```

todo.html

```
<div class="login-page">
    <form class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="login-form">
        <input (change)="onToggle(todo)" type="checkbox" />
    {{ todo.title }}
    <button (click)="onDelete(todo)" class="del">x</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The above is my Html code. In that I try to do insert a Select All and Unselect all button.
I try for the function to Select all Checkboxs.

Comment: will you please add checkbox html code

Comment: This is the Html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Todo.ts
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  selected: boolean;
}   

// todo-item.component.html
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">
  <p>
    <input (change)="onToggle(todo)" type="checkbox" [checked]="todo.selected"/>
    {{ todo.title }}
    <button (click)="onDelete(todo)" class="del">x</button>
  </p>
</div>     

// todos.component.html
<app-add-todo (addTodo)="addTodo($event)"></app-add-todo>
<div>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn action-button" (click)="checkAll()">Select All</button>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn action-button" (click)="uncheckAll()">Deselect All</button>
  <button type="Reset" value="Submit" class="btn action-button" (click)="resetAll()">Reset</button>
</div>
<app-todo-item *ngFor="let todo of todos" [todo]="todo" (deleteTodo)="deleteTodo($event)">
</app-todo-item> 

// todos.component.css
.action-button {
    margin-right: 10px;
}  

// todos.component.ts
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(todos => {
      this.todos = todos;
    });
  }

  deleteTodo(todo: Todo) {
    // Remove From UI
    this.todos = this.todos.filter(t => t.id !== todo.id);
    // Remove from server
    this.todoService.deleteTodo(todo).subscribe();
  }

  addTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.todoService.addTodo(todo).subscribe(todo => {
      this.todos.push(todo);
    });
  }

  checkAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
      this.todos[i].selected = true;
    }
  }

  uncheckAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
      this.todos[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here I have introduced a new property to the todo object called **selected** and it is binded to the checked property of the input.

And I have added two methods named checkAll and uncheckAll to the component which handles select and unselect actions, which needs to get bind to the click event of your SelectAll and UnselectAll buttons.

Those methods will iterate through the todo list and change the value of the  selected property based on the action performed and then the checkboxes will get checked and unchecked correspondly.

Comment: Good.i plan to control through my html button.If I click on the checkall button,all the checkbox in the list have to be checked. Same for the Uncheckall

Comment: It didn't give any reaction on the result.

Comment: So you have list of todos and this ToDoItemComponent handle a single todo item And the SelectAll and UnSelectAll buttons are in a separate component is it?

Comment: Exactly. I started doing this by looking at the angular crash course.

Comment: todos:Todo[]; this is my todo part. I am trying to modify. but it does not work .It show some error. Pls remodify the code as per my requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190339/discussion-between-ponmari-subramanian-and-dilani-alwis).